# can't get page title from notion using api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I'm using notion.py and I'm new to python I want to get a page title from page and post it in another page but when I try I'm getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto_notion_read.py", line 16, in <module>
    page_read = client.get_block(list_url_read)
  File "/home/lotfi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notion/client.py", line 169, in get_block
    block = self.get_record_data("block", block_id, force_refresh=force_refresh)
  File "/home/lotfi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notion/client.py", line 162, in get_record_data
    return self._store.get(table, id, force_refresh=force_refresh)
  File "/home/lotfi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notion/store.py", line 184, in get
    self.call_load_page_chunk(id)
  File "/home/lotfi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notion/store.py", line 286, in call_load_page_chunk
    recordmap = self._client.post("loadPageChunk", data).json()["recordMap"]
  File "/home/lotfi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notion/client.py", line 262, in post
    "message", "There was an error (400) submitting the request."
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: Invalid input.
```

My code is that I'm using is

```
from notion.client import NotionClient
import time
token_v2 = "my page tocken"
client = NotionClient(token_v2 = token_v2)
list_url_read = 'the url of the page page to read'
page_read = client.get_block(list_url_read)
list_url_post = 'the url of the page'
page_post = client.get_block(list_url_post)
print (page_read.title)
```

Comment: Note that an official Notion API is now available (https://developers.notion.com/). It may be wise to consider using it over notion.py if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the fix [here](https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py/issues/292)

In a nutshell you need to modify two files in the library itself:

1. store.py
2. client.py

Find "limit" value and change it to 100 in both.

Comment: where can I find this two files

Comment: This is an on-going issue.
A more appropriate fix is to source this PR instead of editing source: https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py/pull/294#issuecomment-804306525

Comment: I'm wondering why the fix isn't merged into the package itself.

Comment: @Ari Apologies for a newbie question, but how do I source this particular PR? I just edited the code in `store.py` and `client.py` because I don't really know how git PRs work. Would love to know a command that works to install e.g. via `pip`.

Comment: @PAN I added [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69024987/2053706) for you to follow. Please run the `pip uninstall` step then either option 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't recommended to edit source code for dependencies, as you will most certainly cause a conflict when updating the dependencies in the future.

Fix [PR 294](https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py/pull/294) has been open since the 6th of March 2021 and has not been merged.

To fix this issue with the currently open PR (pull request) on GitHub, do the following:

`pip uninstall notion`

Then either:

1. `pip install git+https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py.git@refs/pull/294/merge`

**OR** in your `requirements.txt` add

2. `git+https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py.git@refs/pull/294/merge`

[Source for PR 294 fix](https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py/pull/294#issuecomment-804306525)